# Advantages of Message Inspectors and Value Inspectors in WCF

Tags: wcf

Can any one tell me the advantages of using Message and Value inspectors in WCF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people who create a WCF service will never need them but they can be enormously useful in certain circumstances.

You can have the inspectors both client and server side - on the client side you will usually inspect the message as it goes out and then as it comes in on the server side. When you inspect the departing message you can do things like add values to the headers of the message.

When inspecting incoming messages you can do things like your own custom validation or authentication, or if your service is acting as a relay (i.e. you have a web server that forwards on (or acts as a facade) to an app server) then you can once again add values to the headers of the message.

Note that inspectors can be difficult to get correctly configured (i.e. it is easy to get it wrong), and they can be tough to debug.